# Hiding navigation bar shadow

Tags: android, android-fullscreen

I want to make my app fullscreen. I added this code to onCreate method of activity class.

```
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

However a shadow appears in place of navigation bar. How can I remove that shadow?

sample ss : https://i.hizliresim.com/XEVaa3.png

Answer (score 1):

You can add this in your MainActivity:

```
navigationDrawer.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.someDrawable, GravityCompat.START);
```

You will have to create a drawable that is blank to give it the none shadowing effect. Lemme know how this works :)

Comment: Sorry, it didn't!

Comment: Edited my answer :)

Comment: android:fitsSystemWindows="false" this solved the problem :)

Comment: For details about problem : https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html#behind

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason for my problem : https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html#behind

adding this code solved the problem : android:fitsSystemWindows="false"